# Problem with the order of dictionary entries

Tags: python-3.x

I was showing off some python data types and their functions and attributes about them and one of them was a dictionary and I wanted to reassign the value at the first key and it did reassign it but it also moved the key and its value to a different position and I can't figure out why

I tried this on the Python shell and it gave me the expected result but when I was trying it on GDB online debugger, it gave me the unexpected and wrong results.

This is the snippet of the code that's acting unexpectedly:

```
a=[1, 2, 3, 3, 4]
b={'f':1, 's':2, 't':3, 'fo':4}
b['f']=0
a[0]=0
print(a, b)
```

What I expected was:

> [1, 2, 3, 3, 4] {'f':0, 's':2, 't':3, 'fo':4}

What actually came out:

> [0, 2, 3, 3, 4] {'s':2, 't':3, 'fo':4, 'f':0}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python <= 3.6, `dict`s are unordered.  You should not rely on the ordering of their elements.

In Python >= 3.7, `dict`s are insertion-ordered.  Updating existing values in the `dict` should not affect the order.

In all versions >= 2.7, you can use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) if you need stable ordering.

Based on the behavior you described, I would bet that the GDB online version of Python is older than your local version, *or* you just got lucky when running locally.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries in python don't have any guarantee about their order, so any order you see is purely coincedental. If you want to use a dictionary that preserves the order of elements, you could use an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
b = OrderedDict((('f', 1), ('s', 2), ('t', 3), ('fo', 4)))
```